# Replace every word in text with the word shifted to right 'k' times

Tags: c, string, function, pointers, replace

I tried to make a function which replace every word in a text with the word shifted to right by 'k' times.
the code look like this:

```
void operation_3(char *string, int k){
    int len = 0, i;
    int string_len = strlen(string);
    char *word;
    char s[12] = " .,?!\"'";
    char *dup;
    dup = strdup(string);
    word = strtok(dup, s);
    while (word != NULL) {
            len = strlen(word);
            char *new_word = (char *)malloc(len * sizeof(char));
            for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
                    new_word = shift_to_right(word);
            }
            string = replace_word(string, word, new_word);
            word = strtok(NULL, s);
    }
 }
```

shift_to_right is:

```
char *shift_to_right(char *string){
    char temp;
    int len = strlen(string) - 1;
    int i;
    for (i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            temp = string[i+1];
            string[i+1] = string[i];
            string[i] = temp;

    }
    return string;
}
```

replace_word is:

```
char *replace_word(char *string, char *word, char *new_word) {
    int len = strlen(string) + 1;
    char *temp = malloc(len * sizeof(char));
    int temp_len = 0;
    char *found;
    while (found = strstr(string, word)) {
            if (strlen(found) != strlen(word) || isDelimitator(*(found - 1)) == 1) {
                    break;
            }
            memcpy(temp + temp_len, string, found - string);

            temp_len = temp_len + found - string;

            string = found + strlen(word)

            len = len - strlen(word) + strlen(new_word);
            temp = realloc(temp, len * sizeof(char));

            memcpy(temp + temp_len, new_word, strlen(new_word));

            temp_len = temp_len + strlen(new_word);
    }

    strcpy(temp + temp_len, string);

return temp;
 }
```

and isDelimitator is:

```
int isDelimitator(char c) {
    if(c == ' ' || c == '.' || c == ',' || c == '?' || c == '!' ||
       c == '"' || c == '\0' || c == '\'') {
            return 0;
    }
    else return 1;
 }
```

I tested shift_to_right, replace_word and isDelimitator and work fine. But the final function, operation_3 doesn't work as expected. For example, for input: "Hi I am John" and for k = 1 the output is : "Hi I am John". Basically operation_3 doesn't modify the string. Any advice, corrections please?

Comment: Can you please give an example of "word shifted to right by 'k' times", your posted example tells us nothing as the output is apparently the same as the input.

Comment: Sorry, i was not very precisely. For word = abcd and k = 1, the output should be dabc. So for: "Hi I am John" and k = 1 should be : "iH I ma nJoh"

Comment: In your `replace_word` you have a `if` condition `strlen(found) != strlen(word)` I think `strstr` returns a pointer from within the `string` from where the substring matched, and in that case `strlen(found) != strlen(word)` would always be true, unless the word is the last word in the `string`, so you are breaking from the loop without doing anything in most of the code.

Comment: i tried to make a condition to stop if finds something like this: Johns when i need only John. Strstr finds all substrings. Do you have any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is simpler than what you have, and it prints all the word delimiters that were in the input string. And rather than looking for specific punctuation characters, it checks alphanumeric instead.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    char instr[] = "Hi! I am 'John' ;)";
    int lennin = strlen(instr);
    int shifts, i, len, index, start, next;

    printf("Working with  %s\n", instr);

    for(shifts=0; shifts<5; shifts++) {                         // various examples
        printf("Shifts = %d    ", shifts);
        start = 0;
        while(start < lennin) {
            while (start < lennin && !isalnum(instr[start])) {  // find next alphanum
                printf("%c", instr[start]);                     // output non-alphanum
                start++;
            }
            next = start + 1;
            while (isalnum(instr[next]))                        // find next non-alphanum
                next++;
            len = next - start;
            for(i=0; i<len; i++) {                              // shift the substring
                index = i - shifts;
                while(index < 0) index += len;                  // get index in range
                printf("%c", instr[start + (index % len)]);     // ditto
            }
            start = next;                                       // next substring
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
Working with  Hi! I am 'John' ;)
Shifts = 0    Hi! I am 'John' ;)
Shifts = 1    iH! I ma 'nJoh' ;)
Shifts = 2    Hi! I am 'hnJo' ;)
Shifts = 3    iH! I ma 'ohnJ' ;)
Shifts = 4    Hi! I am 'John' ;)
```

Comment: Thank you, but because i spent a few hours in front of my laptop to make that code i'll probably remain at that form :D. However i think your algorithm it's a little bit sophisticated for my knowledge right now and for me to understand. Thank you again.

Comment: The algorithm finds the index `start` of a word and the `next` index after it. Then it rotates that substring as per your requirement (by manipulating `index`), and moves on to the next word. It's not really sophisticated, but it is more efficient than your algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things which I see are possibly the reason for error.

**1)** In `operation_3` you do this : `new_word = shift_to_right(word);` And, in the definition of `char *shift_to_right(char *string)` you modify the `string` itself and return a pointer to it. So, if you called `shift_to_right(word)` and `word = "Hi"` then after the execution of `shift_to_right` both `word` and `new_word` are now pointing to the same string `"iH"`, so in `replace_word` when you pass both the words and check for the substring `word` you will always get NULL, because, there is no substring `"iH"`.

A possible solution, in `shift_to_right` add a statement,

`char *new_string = strdup(string);`

and instead of swapping the characters in `string`, swap the characters now in `new_string` and return the `new_string` from the function.

Your code shall look like this ::

```
char *shift_to_right(char *string){
    char temp;
    int len = strlen(string) - 1;
    char *new_string = strdup(string);
    int i;
    for (i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        temp = new_string[i+1];
        new_string[i+1] = new_string[i];
        new_string[i] = temp; 
    }
    return new_string;
}
```

**2)** In the function `replace_word`, for a moment let us consider that the above mentioned error does not occur and `replace_word` get called with the parameters :: `replace_word(string, "Hi", "iH");`.
So, when you perform `found = strstr(string, word)`, it gives you a pointer to the first letter where `Hi` started. So, in this case, if your string was `"Hi I am John"`, then you get a pointer to the first `H`, and when you perform `strlen(found)` you will get `12`(length of string left starting from the pointer) as the output, and `strlen(word)` will always be less (unless `found` points to the last word in the string), so in most cases your `if` condition becomes true and you break from the loop, without any swapping.

Moreover, as you yourself pointed out in the comments that `strstr` will return `Johns` as well if you want a substring `John` the only solution for this would be to run a loop and check that in `string` after `John` if there is delimiter character or not, if there is no delimiter character, then this is not the substring that you needed.

`replace_word` shall look something like this ::

```
void replace_word(char *string, char *word, char *new_word) {
    char *found = strstr(string, word);
    int len = strlen(word);
    while(found) {
        char temp = *(found + len);
        if(isDelimeter(temp) == 0) {
            break;
        } else {
            found = strstr(found + len + 1);
        }
    }
    if(found != NULL) {
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            *(found + i) = new_word[i]; // *(found + i) is accessing the i^th, character in string from the pointer found
        }
    }
}
```

I think this `replace_word` shall work, you can directly modify the `string`, and there is no need to actually make a `temp` string and return it. This reduces the need of allocating new memory and saving that pointer.

I hope this could help!

**EDIT ::**  Since we have been using `strdup` in the code, which dynamically allocates memory of the size of the string with an extra block for the `\0` character, we shall take care of freeing it explicitly, so it will be a good idea according to me free the allocated memory in `replace_word` just before we exit the function since the `new_word` is useless after it.

Moreover, I saw a statement in your code::

1) `char *new_word = (char *)malloc(len * sizeof(char));`

Just before you start the shifting the words, I hope you understand that you do not need to do it. `new_word` is just a pointer, and since we now allocated memory to it in `strdup` we do not need to do it. Even before, considering the code that you had written there was no reason to allocate memory to `new_word` since you were returning the address of the array, which was already in the stack, and would stay in the stack till the end of the execution of the program.

Comment: @RobertD haha, I am glad, that could help.:D

Comment: Good and careful explanation. The only note I would expect to see, just to be sure..., is a note regarding the memory allocated by `strdup`. A pointer to the starting address for each new block of memory must be preserved so it can be freed when no longer needed. I haven't stepped through the revised code in depth, but it would be worth a note to make sure that memory isn't falling though the cracks. There is no loss of the starting address in your additions, but I don't see any `free` in the remainder of the code either.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin True.. I will add them now!

Comment: I know i forgot to free the memory. I'll look over again in code and free the memory where it's supposed to be.